# How to design a filter that can filter out noise accurately, after setting the parameters of the filter using standard signal?

Tags: filters, filter-design, digital-filters, adaptive-filters

I meet a problem with designing a filter. I have two different instruments that could measure the same AC signal (usually ~200hz, always <1kHz), ***A*** and ***B***.  **A** can carry out signal measurement during the normal operation of the instrument.
***B*** can only be used during instrument calibration, and ***A*** can also be used at this time. ***B*** can accurately measure the signal. The measurement accuracy of ***A*** is lower than that of ***B***.

I want to design a real-time filter for ***A*** to filter out the interference noise. The parameters of the filter are adjustable. When the instrument is calibrated, both ***A*** and ***B*** are used to measure the signal.
The measurement result of ***B*** is taken as the standard result to calculate the parameters of the filter adaptively. After setting the parameters of the filter, ***A*** is used to measure the signal without ***B***.

I have investigated a variety of filters and found that the adaptive filter is quite suitable for my needs. However, the adaptive filter needs to input two signals, while I can only provide the measurement result of ***A*** during the operation of the instrument. So the adaptive filter is not completely suitable for my needs.

I don't know how to solve this problem. Is there any method that suits my needs?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Is the signal you measure is a pure sine with unknown frequency in the range `(0, 1000)` [Hz]?

Comment: The noise you want to filter is in-band frequency, or out of band frequency?, if the noise is out the frequency range, you can just use a lowpass filter. At the other hand I you want to cancel added noise in a transmission line, perhaps using electric balanced circuitry could help

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a higher precision instrument to measure the signal, then, if the signal maintains it's characteristics, you can build a system's model and use a Kalman filter for the "not so good" input channel.

Comment: My signal to be tested is a pulse signal of 200Hz, with a duty cycle of 20%.
It's like a square wave signal. I have learned the information on the Kalman filter. Is Kalman filter applicable to impulse signal? What I've found is a general use of Kalman filters for filtering continuous signals.

Comment: You can model square waves and PWM (variable duty cycle) syle behaviour by intercepting a horizontal line with a triangular wave. Moving the horizontal line up and down will change the square wave duty cycle. What are your error sources? Frequency? Duty cycle? What are you calibrating?